# Is it possible to filter List View Webpart from URL?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, filter

I have a SharePoint list which I want to filter based on the query string parameter. I have applied the `<parameterBindings>` and when I pass query string parameter it works fine since the list is accessed directly using the URL below.

```
(/site/lists/ListName/MyView.aspx?Filter1=Value1).
```

However, if I am adding a list view web part on the separate page and connecting it together with query string filter web part it does not work and the list view web part returns empty.

DO I need to do something else here?

Comment: did you make sure to follow these steps...https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-a-Query-String-URL-Filter-Web-Part-to-another-Web-Part-8fd0107f-4889-451b-a7f7-d1996e12a8d1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes , It's possible, I tried this on a wiki page and a web part page that worked properly

In your case, there are some points should be checked

- Make sure that the provided filter name at URL is the same name provided in `Query String Parameter Name` within `Query String (URL) Filter` properties.

[image]

**For Example :** If the `Query String Parameter Name` is **Title** the Query String should be like this `https://server/SitePages/Page.aspx?Title=Qassas`

- Make sure that you configure the connection from List to `Query String (URL) Filter` and select `Get Filter values from`

[image]

For more details check [Open a Filtered List URL in a Modal Dialog in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/10/28/open-filter-list-url-modal-dialog-sharepoint/)